# AsyncHttpClient Nested Call Java

Tags: java, android, asynchronous

My goals is to have a nested AsyncCall. The outer call would retrieve information about an event, including the event id, the inner loop would then use the event id to make another call to retrieve the location information of the event. Or is there any way too save the values from an ASYNCHTTP call for future use.

```
    private void populateEvents(String query){
    valueOfQuery = query;
    searchFor(valueOfQuery);
    closeSearchView(searchView);
    client.getInfoByQuery(valueOfQuery,new JsonHttpResponseHandler(){
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONArray eventsObject = response.getJSONArray("events");
                for (int i = 0 ; i < eventsObject.length();i++){
                    Event event = Event.fromJSON(eventsObject.getJSONObject(i));
                    getEventLocal(event.getVenueId(),event);
                    events.add(event);
                    eventAdapter.notifyItemInserted(events.size() -1);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
            Log.i("info","T"+client.finalUrl+responseString);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject errorResponse) {
            Log.i("info","T"+client.finalUrl+errorResponse);
        }
    });
}
public void getEventLocal(String id, final Event event){
    client.getVeneuInformation(id, new JsonHttpResponseHandler(){
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONObject address= response.getJSONObject("address");
                Location location = Location.fromJSON(address);
                event.location = location;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
            super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, responseString, throwable);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject errorResponse) {
            super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, throwable, errorResponse);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONArray errorResponse) {
            super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, throwable, errorResponse);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Then what is issue ?

Comment: My issues is that the first ASYNC ends Before the second one. As a result the location of the event ends up on being null.

Comment: well, do you have any logs?